# Leaflet finding distance to nearest markers on all 4 directions

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a leaflet map with several thousand markers that are clustered. I show an icon for the users current location on the map and I need to show the distance to the nearest marker in all four directions. So for example, North:100M, South:1KM, East:.... and so on.

I dont see an inbuilt way in leaflet to do this. Any ideas on I can go about accomplishing this ?

Comment: What if there's a marker at a 45° bearing (i.e. perfectly north-west)?

Comment: @IvanSanchez For this intent and purpose, it will be considered North.

Comment: Then you don't want the nearest marker in "all four directions", you want "the nearest marker in each of four 90-degree sectors irradiating from the user's position".

Comment: Are we to assume that you want geodetic or cartesian distance, and not manhattan distance, nor distance from the parallel or meridian at the user's position, right?

Comment: @IvanSanchez Yes sir, geodetic distance. Basically this map is for a children's walk and explore type application where the educators want to show the closest "surprise goodies" that are just outside the visible map on the screen. So something like "200 feet up north, you will find hidden dinosaur bones" – w2olves 39 mins ago